# Caveat when stripping HTML tags from strings?

Tags: php, regex, xss

I want to clean away the `<` and `>` characters from an input string, so as to make it "web safe" and avoid script injection mischief.

I know [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) can be used for this, but this will result in a string such as this:

`We are looking at counts < 5000 for this test run` to be truncated to:

`We are looking at counts`.

I would like to have it converted to:

`We are looking at counts 5000 for this test run`

this is not perfect, but less information in the string is lost that way.

I know this can be achieved with for instance regex, but is this in any way unsafe? I mean, is [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) doing something special to the string that a regex which just removed `<>` would not do?

I do not want to use htmlentities() for now, because that confuses our front end code.

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but you may also want to check out [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Comment: @CompuChip I think it's a even better solution to use `htmlentities()` instead of just removing the `<`. Or just use `$convertedBracketStr = str_replace(array('<', '>'), array('&gt;','&lt;'), $str);`

Comment: Tey the regex: /<[A-z\/][^>]*>/ It'll find any <> pairs followed by a character (ie. <p) and then the end >

Comment: @CompuChip, thanks, but for now we have decided to just strip out the characters until we work out a bunch of legacy code which makes it display inconsistently otherwise, if we would use htmlentities()

Comment: @A.Grandt, that would result in the truncated version in my example in the question?

Comment: @Prof. Falken, No, as there are no end >, though rereading your question, I see that you aren't removing the tags, just want to make the string Web Safe. In which case the htmlspecialcharacters function is the one you should go for. The regex I posted is more or less the same as strip_tags, but will only do so if it really IS a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to strip the `<` and `>` use the following code to do so:

```
$str = 'We are looking at counts < 5000 for this test run';

$convertedBracketStr = str_replace(array('<', '>'), null, $str);
```

The result will be: `We are looking at counts 5000 for this test run`

Comment: I am using this solution now. Thanks! If anyone could say why this would be in any way less safe than using strip_tags(), please comment here.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

This will turn <, >, and a number of other characters into their HTML entities so they display correctly on the page.

Comment: Indeed it would in a better world, but it did not answer my question.